# Query to display all tables and views

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I've come up with a query that displays all tables and views of a specific owner. What I would like to do now, but am having an issue with, is that I would like to have a second column which line by line will indicate whether the field is a "table" or "view". Is this possible? if so, how might I go about this?

```
select table_name
 from all_tables
 where owner = '<owner>'
 UNION
 select view_name
 from all_views
 where owner = '<owner>'
 order by table_name;
```

Comment: if you look at objects *owned* by some user you rather need user_tables and user_views...

Comment: @igr, the user_* views will only list the objects owned by the *current* user. The all_* views will list objects owned by an arbitrary owner, which is what the OP needs.

Comment: it seems we interpret differently "...all tables and views of a **specific owner**. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer the xxx_objects views myself for this purpose (as Justin says), but if you specifically need other data from the table and view views, you can add extra info thus:

```
select 'Table' AS object_type, table_name
from all_tables
where owner = '<owner>'
UNION ALL
select 'View' AS object_type, view_name
from all_views
where owner = '<owner>'
order by table_name;
```

Note I've changed it to use UNION ALL because there will be no collisions between the two result sets.

Comment: thats exactly what I was trying to accomplish. thanks

Comment: just want to reiterate that if all you want is the object type and name, you should use the `all_objects` view instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `all_objects` instead

```
select object_name, object_type
  from all_objects
 where object_type in ('TABLE', 'VIEW')
   and owner = <<schema name>>
 order by object_name
```